# phpmailer Error after sending Email

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

[image]

Code: -

```
$mail  = new PHPMailer();
$body="<b>This mail is sent using PHP Mailer</b>";#HTML tags can be included
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth  = true;                 #enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";               #sets the prefix to the server
$mail->Host  = "smtp.gmail.com";         #sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                 #set the SMTP port
$mail->Username   = "morelifelondon@gmail.com";     #your gmail username
$mail->Password   = "***********";                  #Your gmail password
$mail->From = $email;    
$mail->FromName   = $name ;                
$mail->Subject    = "Enquiry";
$mail->Body    = $messages;
$mail->AddAddress("morelifelondon@gmail.com","contact");
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Mail has Been Sent.';
}
}
```

I want that `morelifelondon@gmail.com` is replaced by `abhishek@gmail.com`. Is this possible ?

Comment: That address appears twice in your code, possibly a third time if it's in `$email` (you've not provided complete code). You don't say which instance you want to be different, though all you need to do is change them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->AddAddress("abhishek@gmail.com","contact");
```

or use

```
$mail->AddCC("abhishek@gmail.com","contact");
```

Comment: abhishek is the user  and i want that user's email appear at the place of morelifelondon@gmail.com

    $mail->From = $email;

This piece of code is not working.

Comment: So you have to set your own header.Try to add From: to the header

$headers = "" .
           "Reply-To:" . $from . "\r\n" .
           "From:" . $from . "\r\n" .
           "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Comment: No, **do not** set your own headers - this code is using PHPMailer, which does it for you. If you want to change the from address, just set `$mail->From = 'abhishek@gmail.com';`

Comment: @Synchro Its not working by setting $mail->From ='abhishek@gmail.com'; Still Its showing morelifelondon@gmail.com and i have pasted full code. 
$mail->From ='abhishek@gmail.com';  and $mail->From = $email; is same thing. i guess ?

Comment: We don't know if it's the same thing because you have not shown the part of your code where `$email` is set.

Comment: Try this:

     $mail->SetFrom('xxx@xxx.com', 'XXXXXX');
     $mail->AddReplyTo("no-reply@xxxxx.com","No Reply");